# Spiral Matrix Procedure in Maple

Tags: matrix, maple

I am wanting to write a procedure to take a square matrix and have it output a spiral matrix.

for example;

```
M:=Matrix(3,[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]);
```

would turn into

```
S:=Matrix(3,[[1,2,3],[8,9,4],[7,6,5]]);
```

Starting in the top left corner and each row follows around clockwise until you reach the middle.

My first thought was I need to be able to call each element (m_i,j) from a matrix and tell it where to go. I could write a different procedure for each square matrix assigning where the elements in the matrix each should move to. Since I could not get it to work for n.

Here is what i have for a 3x3 matrix

```
 Spiral := proc(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3)
 local M,S;
 M:=Matrix(3,[[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]]);
 S:=Matrix(3,[[a1,a2,a3],[c2,c3,b1],[c1,b3,b2]]);
 print(M);
 print(S);
 end:

 Spiral(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

It is very difficult for me to find information about Matrices in Maple. Any hint on using Maple would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want S:=Matrix(3,[[1,2,3],*[8,9,4]*,[7,6,5]]); and not: S:=Matrix(3,[[1,2,3],**[9,8,4]**,[7,6,5]]); ?

Comment: yes, I want the last number to be the center.  So m_3,3 -> m_2,2.  For a 3x3 matrix that is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a particularly compact solution to this problem. Here is a solution I came up with. It takes in a square Matrix as input and returns another Matrix which is the spiral of the input Matrix.

```
spiral:=proc(M::Matrix)
    local size, spiralCount, currentRow, currentCol, MIndex, k;
    local spiralMatrix;

    size := numelems(M[1]);
    spiralCount := size;
    currentRow := 1;
    currentCol := 0;
    MIndex := 0;
    spiralMatrix := Matrix(size, size);

    while spiralCount > 0 do
    for k from 1 to spiralCount do
        currentCol:=currentCol + 1;
        spiralMatrix[currentRow,currentCol] := M[iquo(MIndex,size) + 1,(MIndex mod size) + 1];
        MIndex := MIndex + 1;
    end do:
    for k from 1 to spiralCount-1 do
        currentRow:=currentRow + 1;
        spiralMatrix[currentRow,currentCol] := M[iquo(MIndex,size) + 1,(MIndex mod size) + 1];
        MIndex := MIndex + 1;
    end do:
    for k from 1 to spiralCount-1 do
        currentCol:=currentCol - 1;
        spiralMatrix[currentRow,currentCol] := M[iquo(MIndex,size) + 1,(MIndex mod size) + 1];
        MIndex := MIndex + 1;
    end do:
    for k from 1 to spiralCount-2 do
        currentRow:=currentRow - 1;
        spiralMatrix[currentRow,currentCol] := M[iquo(MIndex,size) + 1,(MIndex mod size) + 1];
        MIndex := MIndex + 1;
    end do:
    spiralCount := spiralCount - 2;
    end do:


    return spiralMatrix;
end proc:


> m:=Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]);
                               [1    2    3]
                               [           ]
                          m := [4    5    6]
                               [           ]
                               [7    8    9]
> spiral(m);       
                             [1    2    3]
                             [           ]
                             [8    9    4]
                             [           ]
                             [7    6    5]
```

Feel free to ask me any questions about this implementation and/or about how I to use the Matrix type.